# How to format my Dataframe dates to one format

Tags: python, pandas

I have no idea why but my DataFrame is showing the dates (index) in different formats. Not sure how to fix it.

My Code:

```
csv_m = pd.read_csv('coins_mktcap.csv')

data_m = pd.DataFrame(csv_m)
data_m['date'] = pd.to_datetime(data_m['date'])
data_m.set_index('date', inplace = True)
df_m = data_m.dropna(axis =1, how='all')
```

csv_m output

```
date
12/01/17
13/01/17
14/01/17
...
```

df_m output

```
date
2017-12-01
2017-01-13
2013-01-14
..
2017-01-02
2017-02-02
```

I expect a clean df_m output

```
date
2017-01-12
2017-01-13
2013-01-14
```

Comment: Answer provided by @jezrael is correct ... just use %%timeit  ... so check which one is efficiently working for you . cheers

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add parameters `parse_dates` and `index_col` for `DatetimeIndex` in [`read_csv`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html), also because format with starting days add `dayfirst=True`, check also [docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/io.html#international-date-formats):

```
df_m = pd.read_csv('coins_mktcap.csv', parse_dates=['date'], index_col=['date'], dayfirst=True)
df_m = df_m.dropna(axis=1, how='all')
```

In your solution is possible add same parameter:

```
data_m['date'] = pd.to_datetime(data_m['date'], dayfirst=True)
```

Or specify format:

```
data_m['date'] = pd.to_datetime(data_m['date'], format='%d/%m%y')
```

Comment: i was about to answer this question and u already gave a best solution :)